# LINQ does not recognize joined table in select clause

Tags: c#, linq, syntax-error

I am left joining expected records to a returned set and *attempting* to determine if the expected column was updated correctly. The Column to be updated is determined by a string in the expected row.

**Problem:** I have a compile error I don't understand.

> Cannot resolve symbol dbRow

(where bold/ bracketed by ** in QtyUpdated field).

```
var x = from addRow in expected.AsEnumerable()
        join dbRow in dtDB.AsEnumerable() 
        on  
            new { key1= addRow[0], key2=addRow[1] ,key3=addRow[3] }
        equals 
            new { key1=dbRow["TransactionID"], 
                  key2=dbRow["TransactionItemID"],
                  key3=dbRow["DeliverDate"]
            } 
        into result
        from r in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {TID = addRow[0], ItemID = addRow[1], DeliveryDate= addRow[3], 
            QtyUpdated= (
                addRow[6].ToString() == "Estimated" ? **dbRow**["EstimatedQuantity"] == (decimal)addRow[5] :
                addRow[6].ToString() == "Scheduled" ? **dbRow**["ScheduledQuantity"]==(decimal)addRow[5] :
                addRow[6].ToString() == "Actual" ? **dbRow**["ActualQuantity"]== (decimal)addRow[5] : false)
        };
```

I know this seems wonky, its a tool for Q/A to test that the Add function in our API actually worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `dbRow` is only in scope within the `equals` part of the join. However, you're not using your `r` range variable - which contains the matched rows for the current `addRow`... or `null`.

Just change each `dbRow` in the `select` to `r`. But then work out what you want to happen when there *aren't* any matched rows, so `r` is null.